# VB.net Inserting entry from 1 table to another

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. Can anyone please help?

Here is my code.

```
            Dim addTrans_SQL2 As String = "INSERT INTO Table1(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4) SELECT (Field01,Field02,Field03,Field04) FROM InventoryItems WHERE Field1 = " & c_Field1 & ""
            Dim addTrans_dbcmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(addTrans_SQL2, strCon)
            addTrans_dbcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

c_Field1 has a value of 1.

I already checked the data type of each field in both tables and they are the same.

My strCon connection has no problem.

The only error it says is my INSERT INTO statement.

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: ?? You select `Field01` from `InventoryItems`, but in where clause, you filter `Field1`?

Comment: Yes sir. Would it probably cause the error?

Comment: I tried changing Table1 to other Table with the same data structure of Table1 and it works. So it means my sql statement is correct. So is there something wrong with my Table1?


Anyway, I forgot to mention that my Table1 is being viewed in a DataGridView on the same form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we do not have the table structure, so we assume your `InventoryItems` have `Field01` but not `Field1`

Let's focus on your select statement:

```
SELECT (Field01,Field02,Field03,Field04) 
FROM InventoryItems 
WHERE Field1 = " & c_Field1 & ""
```

The problem is the `Field1` in `Where clause`, you may change it to Field**0**1, which match the selection criteria

```
SELECT (Field01,Field02,Field03,Field04) 
FROM InventoryItems 
WHERE Field01 = " & c_Field1 & ""
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer to close this question, thanks